# CCNet - retrieving built files

Tags: build, cruisecontrol.net, build-automation

I've set up a number of build machines, but I always manually edited the XSL files in the web dashboard so that the build report includes a link to the created output package (typically a ZIP file).
Is there a better way (for example a plug-in) to include a link?  How do you get at the finished product that CCNet exists for?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

**Copy the build package in a folder accessible for web browsing**.
Example in ccnetlive
http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/CCNet-builds/1.4.4/

The link is displayed in this page with the tag  `<externalLinks>` :
http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/server/CCNet%20Live/project/CCNet%201.5/ViewProjectReport.aspx

Comment: The externalLinks tag is interesting.  But I see that it is a static link that is shown whether the build was successful or not.  I'll stick to my customization for now...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the recently-added [Package Publisher](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Package+Publisher).

Update: Note that with CruiseControl.Net 1.5, the packages are available through the cctray application. There is also a Package List package that can be added from the admin screen. I suspect this will show the package links as well.

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for.  My builds already do this.  I'm looking for adding a link to the package just built.  I currently do it by modifying the XSL so that *if* the build is successful, a link shows under the header "Build Successful" pointing to the generated package.

Comment: Are you using some kind of CCNET variables (the CCNetLabel maybe) in your XSL ? If not, how are you linking your *dynamic folder name* ?

Comment: @TridenT: Here's a blog entry where I describe my hack of getting there:  [link](http://blogs.powersoft.ca/erict/archive/2011/12/20/having-a-link-to-the-created-build-in-cruisecontrol.net-again.aspx)